# I don't understand what this error means when working with virtual mouse clicks

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, mouseevent

I'm trying to be able to have a mouse click on current mouse position. While using code from [this site](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/321029-how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-in-c/).

I'm getting an error:

> A call to PInvoke function 'Program!Program.Program::mouse_event' has
>   unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.`at line:`
>   mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);.

I don't understand the problem so what is the cause? How could I fix this?

My code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

public void DoMouseClick()
{
    //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
    int X = Cursor.Position.X;
    int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
}

private void tmrClickInterval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoMouseClick();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DllImport signature is invalid.

The type of `dwFlags`, `dx`, `dy`, and `dwData` is documented as `DWORD`, which is a 32-bit unsigned integer. In C#, `long` represents a 64-bit signed integer. As such, you should use `uint`, which represents a 32-bit unsigned integer .

The last parameter `dwExtraInfo` is a of type `ULONG_PTR` (pointer to an unsigned 32-bit integer), which corresponds to `UIntPtr` in C#.

Try this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

Comment: I don't think I need a closing parenthesis after `"user32.dll"`

Comment: @HelpNeeder: Indeed, fixed it.

Comment: @help: Do note that `mouse_event` has been superseded by `SendInput`. You should probably use that instead.

Comment: Also, there are a couple of issues with your declaration as it stands. First, there's no good reason to use `UIntPtr`; `IntPtr` is fully capable of storing 64-bit pointers. Second, if you're specifying non-relative mouse movement, you'll want to be able to pass negative values. `uint` won't let you do this, so you need to use `int`.

Comment: @Cody Gray, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Help: The `SendInput` function is the recommended way of solving your problem. You should use it instead of `mouse_input`. The documentation for `SendInput` can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx

Comment: I get an error with your modification: `The best overloaded method match for 'Program.Program.mouse_event(uint, uint, uint, uint, System.UIntPtr)' has some invalid arguments` and then `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'uint'`.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: Change `int X = Cursor.Position.X` to `uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X` (and the same for Y).

Comment: Ok, got that working. Just change last type of last parameter: `UIntPtr dwExtraInfo` to `uint dwExtraInfo` and it works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: `dwExtraInfo` represents a pointer and will be 64-bit when you compile for a 64-bit platform. You should use `UIntPtr` to avoid potential problems. If you got errors when using `UIntPtr`, try `System.UIntPtr`.

Comment: @Birunthan Mohanathas, well but then I don't know how to convert int value of 0 to UIntPtr.

Comment: Never mind, just added: `IntPtr newP = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64 ("0", 64)); mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, newP);`

Comment: @Help: The last parameter (`dwExtraInfo`) should be declared `IntPtr` in the function signature, and you should pass `IntPtr.Zero` as the value.

Comment: @Cody Gray, one more question. How to assure I will be able to pass IntPtr.Zero value? I'm quite blank about this.

Comment: @Help: I don't understand what that means. `IntPtr` is a type, just like `Int32` or `String`. It provides a read-only field that is initialized to zero. Calling [`IntPtr.Zero`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.zero.aspx) will therefore always return a zeroed-out `IntPtr`. It just works.